# How to skip <p> tag in HTML?

Tags: html, css, tags, paragraph

I'm trying to use CKeditor as Wysiwyg editor for my blog posts. It works fine, all my contents get inserted fine in DB.

However I have one problem. CKeditor inserts automatic `<p>` tag in the begining, which mess up my code while returning from DB.(I loose CSS stylings).

Therefore, I'm wondering is there a way to tell HTML to ignore(skip) that

tag (and closing one in the end).

Thank you...

Comment: can put some code example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the configuration file **(plugin.js)** to this: `config.autoParagraph = false;`

> Whether automatically create wrapping blocks around inline contents inside document body, this helps to ensure the integrality of the block enter mode.

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.autoParagraph

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the quick answer, but sadly, there's no such file :(... checked every subfolder, everywhere. I'm using basic version, but tried downloading full, and stil, there is no folder wysiwyg area... grrr

Comment: Hmmm, try to find the file "config.js", and add that line I mentioned. Also, be sure to clear the cache.

Comment: Solved, added the line iside config.js. Thank you

Comment: Try adding this extra line: `config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;` and remember, be sure to clear the cache.